# Replacing SELECT statement with something else

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have the following query:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.id, 
        u.login 
        FROM AcmeBundle:Users u
        WHERE 1 = 1";
```

And under certain conditions I want to use something else inside the SELECT clausule, for example:

```
if($count == 1)
{
   $sql = "SELECT COUNT(u.id)
           FROM AcmeBundle:Users u
           WHERE 1 = 1";
}
```

But without writing the whole query again...Inside this if condition, I only want to replace the content of SELECT clausule inside the earlier defined $sql variable...How can I do that?

Something like:

```
if($count == 1)
{
   $sql = str_replace("SELECT ...", "COUNT(u.id)", $sql);
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding `WHERE 1 = 1` It doens't really matter.

Comment: That's just an example, I use it later to apply filters based on GET values, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could use [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax and add a `$select` variable.

```
$select = $count == 1 ? "COUNT(u.id)" : "u.id, u.login";
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT {$select}  
    FROM AcmeBundle:Users u 
    WHERE 1 = 1
SQL;
```

Comment: Ideally, I would like to use some regular expression to match everything between SELECT and FROM, and then replace this...Is it possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I can't see any reason why you need to do a `str_replace` for your query. But you could do `preg_replace("/SELECT(.*)FROM/", "SELECT something else FROM", $sql);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "FROM AcmeBundle:Users u WHERE 1 = 1";

if($count == 1) {
    $beginning = "SELECT COUNT(u.id) ";
} else {
    $beginning = "SELECT u.id, u.login ";
}

$query = $beginning . $sql;
```

Hope you mean that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [QueryBuilder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-using-doctrine-s-query-builder).
Something like this:

```
$builder = $manager->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('p')
        ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:Product', 'p');
```

Will result in `SELECT p FROM AcmeDemoBundle:Product p;` If you now *reset* the `SELECT` like this:

```
$builder->select('COUNT(p)');
```

It will result in this query: `SELECT COUNT(p) FROM AcmeDemoBundle:Product p;`;